# Howto find a keyword in String not between special Tags?

Tags: php, regex, search

im trying to find a list of keywords in a string like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam 
nonumy eirmod tempor <b>invidunt ut labore et dolore</b> magna aliquyam erat, 
sed diam voluptua. <a href="not/replace/me/">dolore</a> ipsum erat.
```

...with the following RegExp:

```
%\b(Lorem)\b(?=[^>]*(<(link|a)|$))%msiu
%\b(dolore)\b(?=[^>]*(<(link|a)|$))%msiu
```

This works at the most time fine. But if other tags inside the string (like bold tag in above example) it finds nothing. If this isn't inside it works fine.

result that i want:

```
<a href="myurl/to/somewhere/">Lorem</a> ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam 
nonumy eirmod tempor <b>invidunt ut labore et <a href="url/to/">dolore</a></b> magna aliquyam erat, 
sed diam voluptua. <a href="not/replace/me/">dolore</a> ipsum erat.
```

At the moment it works only if in the string are no other tags like **B** or else. But if tags like **A** or **link** are inside it also works. Just if other tags inside the string, nothing will be replaced.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for help!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Which language are you running?

Comment: I'll try to search for this keyword and wrap it with a link. I'm using PHP (TYPO3, Extbase)

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Something like <a href="...">Lorem</a> ... tempor <b>invidunt ut labore</b> et .... But also inside the other tags like <b> if a keyword is inside that. But not keywords inside <link>...</link> and not inside <a>...</a>

Comment: What does the `...` mean? could you post the above in your question?

Comment: Modified my question. Hope it shows now better what i want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think i've resolved it:

```
 %(?i)\bMY_KEYWORD\b(?=[^<>]*(?:<\w|<\/[^link|a]|$))%msi
```

in my case it works :)